# How can I adapt a search algorithm in an array of higher and lower numbers to complexity (3n / 2) - 2?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have a program which searches for the largest and smallest number in an array of n elements in the C ++ language. What I want to do is to decrease the complexity of the algorithm a `(3n / 2) - 2`, which currently does not meet this complexity.

This complexity is in the worst case

My question is how can I leave this algorithm to the aforementioned complexity formula? Or what can I modify, delete and add to comply with that condition?

Thank you.
The comparison algorithm is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int arreglo[10] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};
    int menor =0, mayor =0, comparaciones=0;
    menor = arreglo[0], mayor = arreglo[0];
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
        if(arreglo[i]>mayor){
            mayor = arreglo[i];
        }
        comparaciones++;
        if(arreglo[i]<menor){
                menor = arreglo[i];
        }    
        comparaciones++;
    }
    cout<<"Mayor: "<<mayor<<" Menor: "<<menor<<" Comparaciones: "<<comparaciones;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The algorithm has a complexity equation of `5n-2`, I must lower its complexity to `(3n / 2) - 2`

Comment: If your array is sorted (as your post suggests) the winning algorithm is `O(1)`, if the array is not sorted the winning algorithm is `O(n)`.  What's all this about `(3n/2)-2` ?  (Which, in any case, is in `O(n)`.)

Comment: I forgot to mention that this complexity is in the worst case

Comment: Since the C++ standard library contains many algorithms I would simply try `std::min(arreglo, arreglo + 10)` and expect that this function is already implemented. The algorithms of the standard library are usually implemented with optimal time complexity and also efficient for practical use. This doesn't help though for learning how to analyze your own algorithms.

Comment: You might want to clarify why the complexity of your current algorithm is `(3n / 2) - 2`. You are probably using the word "complexity" in a non-standard way; an explanation on where `(3n / 2) - 2` came from might clarify your question.

Comment: No, my algorithm is not `(3n / 2) - 2`, but I want to take it to this same to gain efficiency

Comment: Where did you get `(3n / 2) - 2` from?

Comment: They ask me for an algorithm that complies with that computational complexity, the problem is that, for an array of 10 elements, in that case it makes 18 comparisons, and it must give 13 iterations.

Comment: I notice that if `arreglo[i]>mayor` is true, then it can't possibly also be true that `arreglo[i]<menor`, so you could `else` that second `if`. This would help with the average-case complexity, but not the worst-case, and I don't see a way right now to take advantage of that sort of thing to reduce worst-case.

Comment: Just call `std::minmax_element` which has the right complexity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses the `Divide and Conquer` paradigm.

I based this answer from [this website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-and-minimum-in-an-array/) and there you can see the explanation of why this will take `(3n / 2) - 2` comparisons.

To understand how it works, I suggest getting a pen and paper and follow the code, using a smaller input (e.g.: {3,2,1,0}).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* maxMin(int* values, int begin, int end) {
    int partialSmallest, partialLargest;
    int mid, max1, min1, max2, min2;
    //Here we store Largest/Smallest
    int* result = new int[2];

    //When there's only one element
    if (begin == end) {
        partialSmallest = values[begin];
        partialLargest = values[begin];
    }
    else {
        //There is not only one element, therefore
        //We will split into two parts, and call the function recursively
        mid = (begin + end) / 2;
        // Solve both "sides"
        int* result1 = maxMin(values, begin, mid);
        int* result2 = maxMin(values, mid+1, end);

        max1 = result1[0];
        min1 = result1[1];

        max2 = result2[0];
        min2 = result2[1];
        //Combine the solutions.
        if (max1 < max2)
            partialLargest = max2;
        else
            partialLargest = max1;
        if (min1 < min2)
            partialSmallest = min1;
        else
            partialSmallest = min2;
    }

    result[0] = partialLargest;
    result[1] = partialSmallest;
    return result;
}

int main(){
    int values[10] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};
    int* finalResult = maxMin(values, 0, 9);
    cout << "Largest: " << finalResult[0] << " Smallest: " << finalResult[1];
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `new` like that. Here you can just return a `std::array<int, 2>`.

Comment: The fun part of this is all of the extra stuff going on in the code is probably going to make this slower than the naive approach. What this question really tests is how well you read Knuth.

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer @aschepler, I only have an old c++ compiler at the moment and it's been years since I last used C++, I don't want to risk editting the answer without testing it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't think doing it this way speeds things up.  Whether you divide-and-conquer or not, you still have to examine each item in the array one time.  (What this approach could give you is the ability to multithread the algorithm, although that wouldn't be worthwhile unless the array were much larger than 10 items)

Comment: This task can be done in O(2n-2) using the sequential approach, OP asked for O(3n/2 - 2) which is better than O(2n-2). They're all O(n) in the end. (Disregard the abuse of the O notation :) )

Comment: Remember that algorithm with the best Big O is not necessarily the fastest to execute. The naive approach does more compares, but a lot less of everything else and is running in a nice, straight line. Computers love nice, straight lines.

Comment: Definitely! I would always use the naive approach too.